# Send post data to iframe and reload the iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I tried something something like this using jquery, but i failed.

`$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myphphere.php",
    data: {
        command: $('#command').var()
    }
});`

I also thought about refreshing the page using the onclick attribute of a button to submit the form.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

why just use an `target` attribute in form?

```
<form action="..." target="an_iframe" type="post">
<input type="text" name="cmd" placeholder="type a command here..." />
<input type="submit" value="Run!" />
</form>
<iframe id="an_iframe"></iframe>
```

Hope it solved your problem.

Comment: The question has been solved. This is the best for output a complete console output from phpseclib. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Jquery [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is what you need.

Sending your command to your php script is simple :

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "some.php",
      data: { command: $('#command').val()}
    }).done(function( msg ) {
      alert( "result : " + msg );
  });
```

You can recieve command results and can display that wherever you want (no need to refresh the page)

Comment: This worked for me, but it is too small if i have a complete screen output ;) thanks for this. I would vote the two answers up but icant because of reputation :(